# Struct e lista encadeada

Tags: c, lista-encadeada, struct

Criei uma estrutura do tipo pessoa e pretendo usá-la em uma lista encadeada, porém o seguintes erros aparecem:

> 'No' has no member named 'dados', 'No' has no member named 'prox' e  unknow type name 'p'.

O programa nem chegou a rodar, alguém pode me ajudar?

O arquivo .h é o seguinte:

```
#ifndef Pessoa
#define Pessoa

typedef struct pessoa{
    char nome[25];
    char sobrenome[25];
    int registro;
}Pessoa;

typedef struct no{
    Pessoa dados;
    struct no *prox;
}No;

typedef struct lista{
    No *cabeca;
    No *cauda;
    int tamanho;
}Lista;

No* criaNo(Pessoa p);
Lista* criaLista();
void inserir(Lista *l, Pessoa p, int posicao);
void remover(Lista* l, int registro); //pesquisa registro e remove a pessoa
void imprimeLista(Lista* l);
void destruirLista(Lista* l);

#endif
```

O arquivo .c é o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Pessoa.h"

No* criaNo(Pessoa p)
{
    No* n;
    n=(No*)malloc(sizeof(No));
    n->dados = p;
    n->prox = NULL;
    return n;
}

Lista* criaLista()
{
    Lista* l = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    l->cabeca = NULL;
    l->cauda = NULL;
    l->tamanho = 0;
    return l;
}
void inserir(Lista *l, Pessoa p, int posicao);

{
     //já está pronta, porém não achei necessário colocá-la
}

void remover(Lista* l, int registro)
{
     //já está pronta, porém não achei necessário colocá-la
}

void imprimeLista(Lista* l)
{
    //já está pronta, porém não achei necessário colocá-la
}

void destruirLista(Lista *l)
{
    //já está pronta, porém não achei necessário colocá-la
}
```

Comment: Você viu este `;` sobrando no `.c`? `void inserir(Lista *l, Pessoa p, int posicao);`. Foi só quando passou para cá? O programa compila? Como você chama para testar? Só chama o `CriaLista()`? E o `CriaNo()` E chamado também? Em que linhas ocorrem os erros?

Comment: Confere se estas a incluir o ficheiro .h certo. Chama-se "Pessoa.h" em maiúsculas?

Answer (score 2):

Veja, o que está acontecendo é que você está definindo a palavra `Pessoa` como uma sequência vazia de caracteres para ser substituída pelo [pré-procesador](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9-processador). Por causa do `#define Pessoa`, o que está sendo realmente compilado é:

```
typedef struct pessoa{
    char nome[25];
    char sobrenome[25];
    int registro;
};
typedef struct no{
    dados;
    struct no *prox;
}No;
typedef struct lista{
    No *cabeca;
    No *cauda;
    int tamanho;
}Lista;
No* criaNo( p);
Lista* criaLista();
void inserir(Lista *l, p, int posicao);
void remover(Lista* l, int registro); //pesquisa registro e remove a pessoa
void imprimeLista(Lista* l);
void destruirLista(Lista* l);
```

Veja que toda ocorrência da palavra `Pessoa` desapareceu, por causa do seu `#define Pessoa` (gerei esse código através do comando `gcc -E -C -P pessoa.h`). Se você tivesse usado `#define Pessoa Animal`, toda ocorrência de `Pessoa` seria substituída por `Animal`.

Acredito que o que você está tentando fazer com `#define Pessoa` é usar ["*include guards*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867559/naming-include-guards). Siga o link (em inglês) para mais informações uteis de como faze-lo. Em geral, tome cuidado para que as palavras que você usa não colidam com macros de pré-processador.

Não tem problema a `struct` e o seu `typedef` terem o mesmo nome. No seu lugar eu teria simplesmente feito:

```
typedef struct Pessoa {
  /*...*/
} Pessoa;
```

Além disso, trocaria o `#ifndef/#define Pessoa` para `#ifndef/#define PESSOA_H`

Answer (score 0):

Minha solução para seu problema ficou da seguinte maneira (Pessoa.h):

```
#ifndef Pessoa
#define Pessoa

struct pessoa{
    char nome[25];
    char sobrenome[25];
    int registro;
};

typedef struct no{
    struct Pessoa dados;
    struct no *prox;
}No;

typedef struct lista{
    No *cabeca;
    No *cauda;
    int tamanho;
}Lista;

No* criaNo(struct Pessoa p);
Lista* criaLista();
void inserir(Lista *l, struct Pessoa p, int posicao);
void remover(Lista* l, int registro); //pesquisa registro e remove a pessoa
void imprimeLista(Lista* l);
void destruirLista(Lista* l);

#endif
```

Como pode ver removi o `typedef` da struct pessoa.

Answer (score 0):

O problema era o conflito com seu #Define Pessoa...

vc pode alterar a diretiva e colocar

```c++
#ifndef __PESSOA_H__
#define __PESSOA_H__
   // ... aqui seu código usando typedef
#endif
```